# Gridview sorting not working with Item template

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have a problem, please I hope anyone can help me. I'm trying to sort one datagridview in my job. 
The app has layers and for get data the data layer uses lists.
So, for sorting I try to convert that list in dataTable and using it in GridViewSortEventArgs.
One detail: **I'm using paging**

this is relevant part of my code:

**Define class for the data:**

```
public class Cajas
{
    public Cajas()
    { }

    private string clienteCodigo;
    public string ClienteCodigo
    {
        get { return clienteCodigo; }
        set { clienteCodigo = value; }
    }
    //-------------------------------

    private string cajaCodigo;
    public string CajaCodigo
    {
        get { return cajaCodigo; }
        set { cajaCodigo = value; }
    }
    //-------------------------------

    private int cajaNumero;
    public int CajaNumero
    {
        get { return cajaNumero; }
        set { cajaNumero = value; }
    }
    //-------------------------------

    private string cajaContenido;
    public string CajaContenido
    {
        get { return cajaContenido; }
        set { cajaContenido = value; }
    }
    //-------------------------------

    private DateTime fecEmisionDoc;
    public DateTime FecEmisionDoc
    {
        get { return fecEmisionDoc; }
        set { fecEmisionDoc = value; }
    }


    public Cajas(string cliCod, string cajCod, int cajNum, string cajCon, DateTime fecEmi)
    {
        this.ClienteCodigo = cliCod;
        this.CajaCodigo = cajCod;
        this.CajaNumero = cajNum;
        this.CajaContenido = cajCon;
        this.FecEmisionDoc = fecEmi;

    }

}
```

**In the data layer this is for the query:**

```
    public List<Cajas> Cajas_Buscar_CajaXCont(string clienteCodigo, string cajaContenido)
{
    List<Cajas> ListCajasxContenido = new List<Cajas>();
    string storedProcedure = "CAJAS_BUSCAR_CAJAXCONT";

    using (DbConnection con = dpf.CreateConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = conStr;
        using (DbCommand cmd = dpf.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DbParameter param1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param1.DbType = DbType.String;
            param1.ParameterName = "CLIENTE_CODIGO";
            param1.Value = clienteCodigo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

            DbParameter param2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param2.DbType = DbType.String;
            param2.ParameterName = "CONTENIDO_CAJA";
            param2.Value = cajaContenido;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

            con.Open();
            using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //creamos un objeto de tipo Caja, y por c/ registro encontrado en la db, insertamos
                        Cajas cajaBus = new Cajas();

                        cajaBus.ClienteCodigo = dr["CLIENTE"].ToString();
                        cajaBus.CajaCodigo = dr["CODIGO CAJA"].ToString();
                        cajaBus.CajaNumero = Convert.ToInt16(dr["NUM"].ToString());
                        cajaBus.CajaContenido = dr["CONTENIDO"].ToString();


                        if (Convert.IsDBNull(dr["F.EMI"].ToString())) //para manejar los valores DBnull
                        {
                            cajaBus.FecEmisionDoc = Convert.ToDateTime("9999-01-01"); //de lo contrario c# no los podra interpretar
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cajaBus.FecEmisionDoc = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["F.EMI"]);
                        }

                        ListCajasxContenido.Add(cajaBus);
                    }
                    catch (System.InvalidCastException)
                    { }
                    catch (System.FormatException)
                    { }
                }
            }


        }
    }
    return ListCajasxContenido;

}
```

**for get data on grid I call it**

```
protected void sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont()
{
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = null;
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataBind();
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = cajaBL.sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont(lbl_SacBus_CliCod.Text,
                                                        txt_SacBus_Criter.Text);
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataBind();

    if (gvwSacBus_Docs.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AlertScript", "alert('No Encontrado!');", true);
    }

}
```

**Now for sorting I get this:**

```
public SortDirection dir

{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["CajaContenido"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["CajaContenido"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["CajaContenido"];
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["CajaContenido"] = value;
    }
}
```

**I convert the data to Datatable**

```
public class ListtoDataTable
{
    public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        //Get all the properties by using reflection   
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name); //Setting column names as Property names  
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {

                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

**So, when I try to make the sorting I use:**

```
protected void gvwSacBus_Docs_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = cajaBL.sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont(lbl_SacBus_CliCod.Text,
                                                        txt_SacBus_Criter.Text);
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataBind();
ListtoDataTable lsttodt = new ListtoDataTable(); //convert list to datatable
    databito = lsttodt.ToDataTable(cajaBL.sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont(lbl_SacBus_CliCod.Text,
                                                        txt_SacBus_Criter.Text));

    string SortDir = string.Empty;

    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)

    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        SortDir = "Desc";
    }

    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        SortDir = "Asc";
    }

    DataView sortedView = new DataView(databito);
    sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDir;

    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = sortedView;
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = cajaBL.sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont(lbl_SacBus_CliCod.Text,
                                                        txt_SacBus_Criter.Text);
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataBind();
}
```

**In the gridview I call what i've created:**

```
AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvwSacBus_Docs_Sorting">
```

**the app uses Item templates:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CONTENIDO" SortExpression="CajaContenido">
```

Please, I hope anyone can help me

best regards!!

Comment: Hi VDWWD, I convert list to datatable for generate gvwSacBus_Docs_Sorting (this uses datatable). the gridview uses Item Templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you converting a `List` to a `DataTable`? You can bind List to a GridView.

```
gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = myList;
```

Anyway if you want to sort a DataTable you do it like this. You have to use `ToTable`

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDir;
gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

**I changed my code and It worked, thanks a lot VDWWD**

```
protected void gvwSacBus_Docs_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = cajaBL.sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont(lbl_SacBus_CliCod.Text,
                                                        txt_SacBus_Criter.Text);
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataBind();

    //convertir list to datatable
    ListtoDataTable lsttodt = new ListtoDataTable();
    databito = lsttodt.ToDataTable(cajaBL.sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont(lbl_SacBus_CliCod.Text,
                                                        txt_SacBus_Criter.Text));


    string SortDir = string.Empty;

    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)

    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        SortDir = "Desc";
    }

    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        SortDir = "Asc";
    }


    databito.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDir;
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = databito.DefaultView.ToTable();
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataBind();
}
```